# Can't retrieve user contact picture in Android without using READ_CONTACTS permission

Tags: android, contacts

I am trying to access the Contact Data of an individual contact via intent.  Recently, Google does not require the READ_CONTACTS permission when using an intent to read one contact.  I am able to retrieve the name, phone number email and other data using this method, but retrieving the contact picture does not work.  (If I add the READ_CONTACTS permission in the manifest it does work, but I don't want to have to add this permission as the app only tries to read contacts one at a time via an intent so the user is aware of it.)  Here is the code below.

Starting Intent

```
 Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK); 
 contactPickerIntent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
 startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, CONTACT_PHOTO_STUDENT_RESULT);
```

Later in getting the result

```
if (requestCode == CONTACT_PHOTO_STUDENT_RESULT)
{  Uri contactUri = data.getData();

      ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        InputStream is = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(cr, contactUri);
```

Then I use the inputstream to save as a jpg file
}

Comment: Why is using the `READ_CONTACTS` permission bad?

Comment: It could allow an app to copy all of your contact data.  It is actually a permission I wish Android gave users more control over.  I certainly wouldn't give all my contacts to a random person on the street and don't like that so many apps add that permission.  I'd rather an app have an option in the settings to read contacts if I want to use that feature of the app instead.  Since my app does not need to read contacts without user interaction I'd rather just make do with Android's temporary read permission when using the contact picker intent.